# How to use vue editor multiple times on same page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a page on which I am adding vue editor this editor is present two times as the screen is like a split screen.
On adding my same vue editor ascx control twice on the same page I am getting an error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $url**

On searching for this online I got a few links

https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/36

where it is said that I have to instantiate the vue editor which I think is correct as currently, I am using a hardcoded cdn reference.
But I am not following the steps that are referred in the link can someone please explain as to how they are used? Or is there another way to do the same.

My code is
I have a SplitScreen.aspx page on which I have added the VueEditor Controler twice
On the vueEditor I have added the cdn thit I downloaded and added to my project

```
    <script src="../Scripts/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/vue-document-editor.js"></script>
```

in the vue-document-editor.js I have initialised the vue editor

```
var initVue = function initVue(apiUrl) {

    baseApiPath = apiUrl;
    console.log(baseApiPath);

    }
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @ThomasKleßen I have updated the question for the code. Apart from this, there is much of the business logic and variable name

Comment: Is that really it for the document editor file? When is that function called? The issue you linked states that when you import the file directly, as you have, the file calls the instantiator automatically. `If you directly import vue.js and vue-resource.js, *Vue.use(VueResource)* is executed automatically by the Vue Resource plugin.`

Comment: unrelated: Why do you need to use vue-resource? There are plenty of alternatives: https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4

Comment: Does that mean I don't have to do the vueify steps that are mentioned on the post? Cause I think the redefining is caused as I am using the same control twice. When added the any one of the two VueEditor controlers on the page everything worked fine

Comment: post your code and we can help more, but if you're not using ES Modules, require(), AMD, etc, and a build step, then yeah, you probably don't need to instantiate the vue-resource plugin.

Comment: Fundamentally, you only need to use `Vue.use(AnyVuePlugin)` once, usually only in the main.js as a general convention.

Comment: I changed the approach of the using the Vue. So instead of using the same editor twice on same page, I added a new component on the vue editor and then add css for split screen design. So the Cannot redefine property: $url was solved.